# How can I filter queries in view.py and render them into the template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I understand the querying from a basic perspective. That is if I write:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.jurisdiction}}
{% endfor %}
```

It will for every row item in my database table which has an entry in the "jurisdiction" column capture that row and return just the "jurisdiction".

What I really want to do is to return things filtered. From what I've heard the backend is where the querying/filtering should be done. To me, this means creating the query and filter in views.py

Now, what I really want to do is filter by multiple parameters. "Jurisdiction" + "Retention_Rule", for example.

I'm looking for an explanation of how to create a filtered query in views.py and then rendering it in the index.html (or other template). Also, want to know who to do multiple different kinds of queries that can be used in a template page.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.http import Http404

from inventory.models import Item 

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    items = Item.objects.filter(jurisdiction="Germany") 
    return render(request, 'inventory/index.html', {
        'items': items, 
    })

    test = Item.objects.filter(jurisdiction="China").filter(record_type="Exit Interview")
    return render(request, 'inventory/index.html', {
        'test': test, 
    })
```

The "test" doesn't render and isn't called. However, I just put that there to help me think about how to create different kinds of filtered queries that can be accessed in the template.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    jurisdiction = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    business_function = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    record_category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    record_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    retention_rule = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1,max_digits=3)
    retention_trigger = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    personal_data = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    privacy_driven = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**index.html**

```
{% for item in items %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>{{ item.jurisdiction }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ item.record_category }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ item.record_type }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ item.retention_rule }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ item.retention_trigger }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ item.personal_data }}</h1>
            <h1>{{ item.privacy_driven }}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Think of view function is just another normal function. The test is  not rendered because the function is already returned. Once the function returns anything no further lines would be executed.

You can pass multiple filtered queries to template by passing all the querysets in the context.

```
return render(request, 'inventory/index.html', {'items': items, 'test': test})
```